# passport oauth/authorize always redirect login fixed, but Client authentication failed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

when I request url redirect, I can't get access_token, It always redirect to login

```
// First route that user visits on consumer app
Route::get('/redirect', function () {
    // Build the query parameter string to pass auth information to our request
    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => 1,
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://app_golf.xiongmaojf.com/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => 'crud-bookmark-collections crud-bookmark-tags crud-bookmarks'
    ]);
// var_export($query);
    // Redirect the user to the vOAuth authorization page
    return redirect('http://golf.xiongmaojf.com/oauth/authorize?' . $query);
});

// Route that user is forwarded back to after approving on server
Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://golf.xiongmaojf.com/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => 1, // from admin panel above
            'client_secret' => 'LNJhtWdGsDTQmei9x4lAh2BBfOmQkqXG3jdOjGRL', // from admin panel above
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://app_golf.xiongmaojf.com/callback',
            'code' => $request->code // Get code from the 
        ]
    ]);

    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];
});
```

but request url oauth/authorize, I can't get token, it always redirect to login,

I solved this problem, because I'm not login, I'm so sorry for that,  but when I'm logined, request url oauth/authorize , It always require userName and password for golf.xiongmaojf.com, any userName and password is not useful,

[image]

and if I clieck Cancel  It responsed

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "message": "Client authentication failed"
}
```

I solved this problem by reigster new app_client use oauth/clients, and got this page 
[image]

I got access_token

Comment: I have solved problem about redirect  to /login , but i got an another problem, it response Client authentication failed

Answer (score 0):

delete all oauth table:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=5
```

and migrate all :

```
 php artisan migrate
```

and:

```
 php artisan passport:install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had given same url http://app_golf.xiongmaojf.com/callback when create a new OAuth client in provider.

This dialog box can be shown when your url are not the same.

If it wouldn't help, please also try to generate a new key using:

```
php artisan passport:keys
```